# Get list of phone numbers without particular digit

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to get a list of numbers from a table with a particular digit not included in it.

For example, I have the following phone numbers:

```
555-1234
555-2468
555-3690
555-5050
555-6789
555-7777
```

How can I get back the list of phone numbers which do not have 6 in it?

Comment: 555-1234    
      555-2468    
      555-3690    
               
      555-5050    
      555-6789    
      555-7777

Comment: i am using Sqlite3.

Comment: i don't know hoe to add the table in this thing, but there is a list of phone numbers and i just want to get back numbers which does not have 6 in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say the column name is phone and table name is Contact then,

```
SELECT phone FROM Contact WHERE phone NOT LIKE '%6%';
```

Comment: Thanks Robin!!! this is what i was looking for. just want to ask now what if i want to add null spaces in that? coz in the data there where a few customers who do not have a phone  so the space was left blank.

Comment: do you want to skip the null values?

Comment: then use something like: 

SELECT phone FROM Contact WHERE phone NOT LIKE '%6%' OR phone IS NULL